# Tracking Distributed Marketing Links Entered by End User

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, distributed-marketing

We are successfully using Distributed Marketing and the end users (those adding custom language and triggering the send from Sales Cloud), are also adding links to the email using the Distributed Marketing Rich Text Block that is built into the email.

However, the links the end user adds are not being tracked by Marketing or Sales Cloud when the recipient clicks on them. Any links built into the email template are being tracked. It is only the custom links that the end user adds that are not being appropriately tracked.

Is there any extra code needed around the DM Rich Text Block to ensure links added by the end user are tracked?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the tracking of links added by the end user, change the code of the DM Rich Text Block as shown here. This solution was confirmed by Salesforce support. Once implemented, link tracking is captured for each URL entered by the end user.

Replace:
%%=v(@richTextMsg)=%%

With: 
%%[ SET @cleanedRichTextMsg = REPLACE(@richTextMsg, '"http', '"httpgetwrap|http')
]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(@cleanedRichTextMsg)=%%

Comment: Make sure that Salesforce has enabled WRAP HTTPGET URLS for you in the BU(s) that you need this for, for the above solution to work.